# Access images in React through Rails Active Storage using JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, rails-activestorage

I'm making a Rails API where I would like to use Active Storage to attach images to posts and then be able to access them in REACT, such as getting the url link in JSON. How do I convert the Active Storage images to urls for JSON. Is there a better way to be able to get the link to the images for the posts?

For example, I would want the image url to be included in this information:

From: http://localhost:3001/api/posts

```
[{"id":8,"title":"lolol","body":"lolol","created_at":"2018-07-19T23:36:27.880Z","updated_at":"2018-07-20T00:17:50.201Z","admin_user_id":1,"post_type":"Song","link":"dgdadg","song_title":"dgdadg","tag_list":[]},{"id":13,"title":"ddd","body":"dd","created_at":"2018-07-20T00:21:39.903Z","updated_at":"2018-07-20T00:21:39.907Z","admin_user_id":1,"post_type":"Song","link":"dddd","song_title":"ddd","tag_list":["Tag"]}]
```

Here is my Post Controller :

```
class PostsController < ApiController
    before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    if params[:tag]
      @posts = Post.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else
      @posts = Post.all
    end

    render :json => @posts
  end

  def show
    @post
    render :json => @post
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
  end

  def update
    @post.update(post_params)
    head :no_content
  end

  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    head :no_content
  end

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :song_title, :post_type, :admin_user_id, :link, :tag_list, :image)
  end

  def set_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Have been there like 2 weeks ago and decided against ActiveStorage because of the exact same issue. You can do some controller magic that uses

```rb
url_for(@post.image)
```

like

```rb
render :json => @post.merge({image: url_for(@post.image)})
```

or something along those lines

```rb
class Post
  def image_url
    Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_path(self.image, only_path: true)
  end
end
    
# controller
render :json => @post.as_json(methods: :image_url)
```

Comment: The first way, I got undefined method merge, and the second way I got undefined method url_for $<Post...> Is there something else I need to add to get those to work. Also, do you have any suggestions on what you used, if you didn't use Active Storage, I'm open to different suggestions!

Comment: I withdraw my second suggestion. seems the method is not available on the model. You could try to fiddle around with `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_path(post.image, only_path: true)`. For the first solution I can't help you since since the issue is not the `url_for` but the `.merge`. I still use paperclip. Its deprecated in favor for activestorage but still works fine.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible within jbuilder to access the `url_for` helper. So your `_post.json.jbuilder` could work something like this

```ruby
json.extract! post, :id, :body, :created_at, :updated_at
if post.image.attached?
  json.image_url url_for(post.image)
end
json.url product_url(product, format: :json)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `Post` model has an `ActiveStorage::Attachment` you can just call 
`@post.file.service_url` or `@post.file.public_url` assuming you have `has_one_attached :file` in your model.